# How to upgrade Ruby with Railsinstaller from 1.9.3-p125 to 1.9.3-p327?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The railsinstaller worked fine, but I cannot figure out how to upgrade Ruby to 1.9.3-p327 while keeping evrything else working properly. I'm new to this technology, so I apologize if the answer to this question is super obvious.

Enivironment: Windows 7 Home Premium - Service Pack 1 - 64-bit

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: Agreed. I been hacking rails on windows for a few years. Is not working very well. Rails and a lot of the gems specially in testing depend on a UNIX framework. I installed ubuntu on a viritualBox and have not looked back since. Then you can use rvm, and upgrading is easy

Comment: Thank You Andreas! I will give ubuntu a try. Kirk out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your operating system, which I would suggest as mint/ubuntu are quite easier for programming ruby,  you can use pik ( https://github.com/vertiginous/pik ). I'm using it since too years on a Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

After you installed pik it'll detect your currently installed rubies. After that you can download new rubies, add them to pik and choose the ruby on every command line.

```
pik use 193 # to select the current ruby 1.9.3
```

The functionality is not as big as rvm but it's an alternative if you need to work on windows as it's the common operating system in offices.